# Listing industry related honors and awards on a CV

Tags: cv, awards

I'm in the process of getting my PhD as part of a transition from industry to academia. During my time in industry I received a number of awards that I've typically listed in one form or another on my résumé. What is the protocol for listing these on the academic CV? Should they just be put in a generic "Honors and Awards" section, or broken out by industry, academic, etc?

Since it may be relevant, the awards loosely breakdown as follows:

- Awarded within the department
- Nominated by department, awarded by higher level management
- Annual award from the highest level of a multi-national organization

These were also a combination of individual and team awards as well.

Comment: I would go with the "Honors and Awards" section where you put all awards, from industry and academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you add to your C.V. any awards that are relevant to your potential and performance as a researcher.

For example, one of my colleagues was recently given an internal "Entrepreneurial Award" for developing a significant line of business around research that he has been leading.  Even though this sounds kind of "businessy," it would be a good award to list on a C.V. because it is actually about his abilities as a researcher.  On the other hand, another person at the company was given an award for their flexibility in handling scheduling challenges of National Guard employees, and I would not recommend listing that on a C.V., since it is not relevant to scientific ability.

Finally, it's a good idea to add a short explanation on your C.V. for any awards that are not obvious from their title: e.g., "Best paper at Conference X" needs no explanation, but something like "Entrepreneurial Award" or "Hertz Foundation Fellow" should have a few words saying what that means, for those who aren't familiar. (See [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10692/22733) for more on explanations)